# Are ex military airplanes experimental?

Tags: experimental-aircraft

What makes a plane experimental, and why do all warbirds categorize as experimental aircraft?

Comment: Where did you find the info that all warbirds are categorized as experimental?

Comment: Does this need an 'FAA-Regulations' tag?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"Experimental" refers to a particular category of [airworthiness certification](https://www.faa.gov/aircraft/air_cert/airworthiness_certification) available for an aircraft. [14 CFR §91.203](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/91.203) requires all "civil aircraft" to have an airworthiness certificate, basically a piece of paper saying "someone has convinced the civil aviation authority that this particular plane is fit to fly."

There are two broad groups of certification categories: "standard" and "special." Your typical GA aircraft or airliner has a "standard" airworthiness certificate, which is based on the manufacturer's [type certification](https://www.faa.gov/aircraft/air_cert/design_approvals). The manufacturer (say, Cessna) spent millions of dollars to get this type certification, and that makes it easy for Cessna owners to get a standard airworthiness certificate as long as their aircraft conforms to the specifications in the type certificate.

But of course a military aircraft doesn't necessarily have a civil type certification, because in its intended role, it didn't need one. Neither the manufacturer nor a private owner has much interest in spending the millions of dollars needed for a full type certification. So instead of applying for a standard airworthiness certificate, the owner looks at [the various options](https://www.faa.gov/aircraft/air_cert/airworthiness_certification/sp_awcert) for special airworthiness certification. A warbird isn't a "light sport" aircraft, or an ultralight, or a cropduster, etc. which rules out most of the available categories.

That leaves...

- the [experimental](https://www.faa.gov/aircraft/air_cert/airworthiness_certification/sp_awcert/experiment) category:

  > A special airworthiness certificate in the experimental category is issued to operate an aircraft **that does not have a type certificate** or does not conform to its type certificate and is in a condition for safe operation.
- and, for types that do in fact have a civil type certificate, the [limited](https://www.faa.gov/aircraft/air_cert/airworthiness_certification/sp_awcert/limited) category:

  > A limited category special airworthiness certificate is issued to operate **surplus military aircraft** that have been converted to civilian use under the following conditions:
  >
  > ...
  >
  > - The aircraft **has a limited type certificate**.

Some warbirds, like the [P-40 Warhawk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curtiss_P-40_Warhawk), do [have a limited type certificate](https://www.pilotweb.aero/news/legal-fight-over-warbird-training-8317304) and can get limited airworthiness certificates.

<sub>* The links and citations here are US/FAA-centric, but many (most?) countries' civil authorities have very similar certification systems.</sub>

Comment: You missed the ["restricted" category](https://www.faa.gov/aircraft/air_cert/airworthiness_certification/sp_awcert/restrict) where the aircraft is intended for specific, special operations. This is the most common category for military aircraft holding civil certification. The C-130/L-100, A400M, and P-3 are all examples holding a restricted TC. The key difference is a limited category aircraft can't be used for hire.